# How to dynamically disable and enable foreign key check in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to move entries from my old tables to the new one with the updated schema. The problem is, I have to move content from 10 tables with old config to 10 tables with the new config.

I am doing this with the help of console command. When I add the new table and execute the command, I get Duplicate entry error for the tables that already have data which is obvious.

When I try to use `DB::connection('mysql_old')->table('users')->truncate();`, It throws `1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint` Errror which is obvious too!

Here is how I am moving entries from old tables to the new one.

```
$entries = DB::connection('mysql_old')->table('users')->get();
DB::table('users')->truncate();
foreach($entries as $entry){
    $user = \App\User::create([
        'name' => $entry->name,
        'email' => $entry->email,
        'status' => $entry->status,
        'credits' => $entry->credits,
        'role' => $entry->user_role,
        'email_subscription' => $entry->email_subscription,
        'activation_key' => $entry->activation_key,
        'password' => $entry->password,
        'remember_token' => $entry->remember_token,
        'created_at' => $entry->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $entry->updated_at
    ]);
}
```

The only solution is to disable foreign key check before truncate and enable it again after truncate (I think). It is a relational database as obvious. So, is there any better way to complete this task?

I thought about giving a try to move entries from old table to the new one in `a relational way` but it is not possible in this case.

I can execute the command `php artisan migrate:refresh` every time the command is executed. But here is the problem with that, There are more than 25 tables and It takes about 20-30 seconds to complete `migrate:refresh`.

I am really confused how to get this done. Is there any proper or standard way?

Comment: Consider using a plain old mysqldump for this. It's probably going to be easier.

Comment: already found solution @apokryfos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to turn off and turn on the foreign key check. Here is how I moved information from old table to new one.

```
// Disable foreign key checks!
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

// Move users from old table to the new one
$entries = DB::connection('mysql_old')->table('users')->get();
DB::table('users')->truncate();
foreach($entries as $entry){
    $user = \App\User::create([
        'name' => $entry->name,
        'email' => $entry->email,
        'status' => $entry->status,
        'credits' => $entry->credits,
        'role' => $entry->user_role,
        'email_subscription' => $entry->email_subscription,
        'activation_key' => $entry->activation_key,
        'password' => $entry->password,
        'remember_token' => $entry->remember_token,
        'created_at' => $entry->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $entry->updated_at
    ]);
}

// Enable foreign key checks!
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

It worked!

Answer (score 18):

You can do this:

```php
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

// Your database operations go here..

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: I did this `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');` to turn off and `1` to turn on. It worked! This solution is better for the specified problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have migration table just make index to attribut like this:

```
just make ->index
like this 
$table->unsignedBigInteger('city_id')->index();
 $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')
 ->on('cities')->onDelete('cascade');
```